# How to extract sender and receiver date from .msg file using apache-poi in java

Tags: java, apache-poi, mapi

I am using Apache-POI library to extract **.msg** file data and i got all the details. but i am not able to retrieve sent date and received date. So is there any way to retrieve both dates from **.msg** file using this library.

I am using MAPIMessage class to fetch all data from **.msg** file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't you need to get the headers and parse them for this?

Comment: Have you had a look at [the JavaDocs of `MAPIMessage`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/hsmf/MAPIMessage.html)? There is [`getMessageDate()`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/hsmf/MAPIMessage.html#getMessageDate--), maybe one of the dates you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply and yes this method return me the sent date but i also want the date once receiver get the mail.